# keep the mouse over color on mouse out

Tags: css

I am actually changing the color of link & its background on mouse over. When I move the cursor  to sub menu item the text of parent menu revert back to white. I did try to use a:active to resolve this issue but no luck.

please check the main navigation on this site http://kushian.com

for css
http://kushian.com/catalog/view/theme/red15/stylesheet/stylesheet.css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is more of a guess (make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) maybe?), but i think

```
#menu > ul > li > a:hover{
    color:maroon;
}
```

needs to be

```
#menu > ul > li:hover > a{
    color:maroon;
}
```

Comment: Without a fiddle or without the full code I can't be completely certain, but it seems like your answer is the best option. It's hard to make things stay with CSS while you do other actions.

Comment: Yes, although IE6 ignores :hover on all elements except for `<a>`, so if IE6 is a requirement then this solution isn't sufficient by itself

Comment: @Gareth if that's the case, the only possible solution will be with jQuery or straight js :P

Comment: perfect, I was getting too much frustrated because of this problem. Thanks a Lot for quick support

Comment: @Fahad You're welcome. XD I'm just glad my untested solution worked. :P